# Как сделать вывод просроченных записей, записей на завтра и на будущую неделю

Tags: php

Писал скрипт, но он не работает так как нужно.

Суть в том, что при добавлении комментария, клиенту в базу заносится 2 даты:

**client_dateA** - дата последнего контакта;

**client_dateB** - дата следующего контакта;

В системе есть вывод клиентов по дате, но он работает как-то странно, мне нужно, чтобы выводило количество записей **COUNT(client_id)**, для которых дата следующего контакта будет меньше, чем текущая дата дня (это считается просроченной записью, если менеджер её не прокомментировал за целый день и на следующий день она становится просрочкой) также нужно вывести количество клиентов, у которых дата следующего контакта назначена на завтра и на неделю.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как грамотно это сделать.

Код, который делает запрос сейчас

```
<?php   

// Подключение скриптов ядра
include 'engine/function_mysqlServer.php';
include 'engine/function_configServer.php';
// Подключение скриптов ядра

// Проверка авторизации пользователя
if (isset($_COOKIE['id']) and isset($_COOKIE['hash'])) 
{    
    $userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_id = '".intval($_COOKIE['id'])."' LIMIT 1"));
    $username = $userdata['users_login'];
}
// Проверка авторизации пользователя

// Вывод 40 записей о клиентах на сегодня
$main = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."' and client_dateB = '".$date."' LIMIT 40");

if ($date == $row['client_dateB']) 
{
    while ($row_arr = mysql_fetch_array($main)) 
    {
            echo "<div class=\"content_min\">";
            echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;float:left;font-weight:500;color:#949494;\">".$row_arr['client_company']." (ID: ".$row_arr['client_number'].")</p>";
            echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;float:right;font-weight:500;color:#949494;\">".$row_arr['client_name']."</p><br>";
            echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;float:left;font-weight:500;color:#949494;\">".$row_arr['client_dateA']."</p>";
            echo "<p style=\"font-size:14px;float:right;font-weight:500;color:#949494;\">".$row_arr['client_phone']."</p><br><br>";
            echo "<p style=\"line-height:20px;color:#676666;\">".$row_arr['client_comment']."</p></div>";
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "<div class=\"mess_coffe\">".$username.", на сегодня у Вас отсутствуют записи</div>";
}

    // Общее количество зарегистрированных клиентов менеджером
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."'");
    $res_sql = mysql_fetch_row( $sql );
    // Общее количество зарегистрированных клиентов менеджером

    // Просроченные записи на текущий день
    $overdue = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."' and client_dateB < NOW()");
    $overdue_result = mysql_fetch_row( $overdue );
    // Просроченные записи на текущий день

    // Зарегистрированные клиенты на завтра
    $tomorrow = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM client WHERE client_manager = '".$username."' and client_dateB > '".$date."'");
    $tomorrow_result = mysql_fetch_row( $tomorrow );
    // Зарегистрированные клиенты на завтра
```

Comment: храните время в формате DATETIME и используйте DATEDIFF http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp, и NOW() в запросах

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пример вашего запроса, который не работает